# Multilevel drop down menu jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Greetings!

I have a jquery drop-down menu which is not multilevel like this - http://javascript-array.com/scripts/multi_level_drop_down_menu/?j (see Example in the link).
Here is my complete code - http://www.filedropper.com/projectv5210_1

I want to make the above menu multilevel. Please help me to edit the above code to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest that put your code in [Jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net)

Comment: OK! Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k7EV6/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you haven't nested any ul tags, inside a li tag for two levels.
Try replacing

```
<li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

with

```
<li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="about-us.html">A</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about-us.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="about-us.html">C</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

You may still have css issues in the fiddle as multimenu.css has not been included.
Hope this solves ur issue

Comment: I actually don't see it. You have a ul tag for "nav" then li having a ul inside it. What you need is another level of ul and li. Here try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7EV6/2/
Check for the link Home>>A>> 
However i still see styling issues as the require style sheet may not have been included

Comment: I saw the fiddle. Actually this is the issue. The inner most menu should open on either left or right side. See the example in my first post.